# Java/Maven Project has red X's on all imports not starting with Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, importerror

After system recovery and a reinstall I re-imported one of my projects.  I have tried cleaning the project, doing a maven update, maven install, etc.  However, in the import section in my .java files I am getting red X's on every single import that isn't java.  Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.List
```

Import without a problem.  However:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.camunda.spin.json.SpinJsonNode
import static org.camunda.spin.Spin.S
```

All have a red X in front of the import line.  When I do a clean package or run, everything is fine.  If I try to use something involved with one of the elements that I've imported such as trying to use completion from SpinJsonNode it won't give me auto completion.  Is there something that I need to do in order for this to work?

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Spring Tool Suite 4, version 4.12.1.RELEASE

Comment: Really that old: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4 ???

Comment: Oh, if I mouse over the red X I get something like "The import org.camunda cannot be resolved"

Answer (score -1):

Ok, solved the problem.  Unbeknownst to me, a coworker was also working on this and for some reason pushed a bad classpath up to our repo, then I pulled it down, and he immediately fixed it.  Stupidly, I didn't check for what was pulled down.  After rebuilding the classpath it worked fine.